# Reading geojson properties in openlayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

My code is very simple. This is my vector-source and this is how I render my geojson :

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   url: 'some_geojson_is_here'
});
```

Then I pass this vectorSource as a source to a vector layer etc etc. Now I'm wondering is there any way I can get every feature this geojson has??

In this link : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html the 3-rd method it's what I think the way to get all features but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the features from the `vectorSource` with the function [getFeatures()](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeatures).

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   url: 'some_geojson_is_here'
});

var vectorFeatures = vectorSource.getFeatures();
```